# Why does this jQuery .change event stop working after .click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that displays questions from an array and switches from one question to the next using the `.click` event on two buttons: previous and next. When I load the page the `$(":radio").change` selector works fine, but when I click on previous or next it stops working.

I tried changing the `$("#previous)` to a console.log to see if `.click` was the culprit and it seems to be working. I assume there is something wrong with my display function but I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeanpierreb/ohdL7eyc/). And here is the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/jeanpierreb/js-quiz-app)

**Questions Array**

```
var quizQuestions =
[{
    question: "1. Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
    correctAnswer:0
},
{
    question: "2. Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
    correctAnswer:2
},
{
    question: "3. Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
    correctAnswer:1
}];
```

**JavaScript Code (jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var all = quizQuestions,
        q = $("#question"),
        c = $("#choices"),
        ans = [],
        current = 0;

    display(current);

    function display (id) {
        var question = all[id].question;
        var choices = all[id].choices;

        q.html(question);
        c.html(function(){
            var output = "<form>";
            for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                output += "<input type='radio' name='question" +id
                + "' value='" + choices[i] + "'> "
                + choices[i] + "<br>";
            };
            output += "</form>"
            // console.log(output);
            return output;
        });
    };

    function changeDisplay (dir) {
        if (dir == 'next' && current < all.length-1) current++;
        if (dir == 'prev' && current > 0) current--;
        display(current);
    }

    function answerQ (q, a) {
        ans[q] = a;
        console.log(ans);
    }

    $(":radio").change(function(){
        answerQ( $(this)[0].name, $(this).val() );
    });

    $("#previous").click(function (){ changeDisplay('prev'); });
    $("#next").click(function (){ changeDisplay('next'); });

    // console.log("all.length: " + all.length + " | ans: " + ans + " | current: " + current);
});
```

Comment: There is a `console.log` that I couldn't display on fiddle. It's supposed to display the `name` and `value` of the question/answer being selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely because the event is not delegated. When the page is loaded you bind the  click events. But as the dom is manipulated (elements removed) the events are deleted. You would have to use a [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this.

Like this:

```
$('.container').on('change', ':radio', function(){
    answerQ( $(this)[0].name, $(this).val() );
});
```

**Edit:** I would suggest that you save or hide the answers instead of overwriting them. That would make it easier to implement the previous function.

Comment: He was wondering about the change handler, not the click handler but the same theory applies.

Comment: I thought `$("#previous").click(function (){ changeDisplay('prev'); });` was shorthand for what you wrote. Am I wrong?

Comment: @jeanpier_re It is not the same. $("#previous").click bind to the element with "previous" as id. Where as the "on" delegate binds to the body element and listens for a click event on #previous. So that previous can be removed and the event is still attached.

Comment: @TylerMarien I missed that! updated my answer. I also narrowed down the selector to .container as ":radio" together with "body" might target other events :) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like when you move to the next set of questions you replace the HTML on the page for each radio button. However you never assign click handlers to the new radio buttons. You do this initially to all radio buttons when the page is loaded, but after you change the display you don't reapply the click handler to the radio buttons.

In your document.ready handler you have this near the bottom:

```
    $(":radio").change(function(){
        answerQ( $(this)[0].name, $(this).val() );
    });
```

But in the display function (called when you choose previous or next) you have this:

```
        c.html(function(){
            var output = "<form>";
            for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                output += "<input type='radio' name='question" +id
                + "' value='" + choices[i] + "'> "
                + choices[i] + "<br>";
            };
            output += "</form>"
            // console.log(output);
            return output;
        });
```

Which doesn't add a click handler to any of the new input options.

Comment: Good point. How do you suggest I accomplish that? I'm not entirely sure how to approach this one.

Comment: There are several ways you could do it. I'd probably add a class to the form and then use a selector in my jquery statement to apply the change

$(".options:radio").change(function(){
    answerQ( $(this)[0].name, $(this).val() );
));

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem, when you directly add listeners like ".click()" or ".change()", etc, to an element, you're only setting the listener for that object specifically.  To create a listener that applies to all elements currently on the page, and also any future elements created through dynamic means (ajax, new elements added via javascript after page load completes) you should set a `document` level "on" function:

Change what you have here:

```
$(":radio").change(function(){
    answerQ( $(this)[0].name, $(this).val() );
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("change", ":radio", function(){
    answerQ($(this).name, $(this).val());
});
```

(I don't think the [0] on $(this) means anything, because at that moment it would only apply to the element that was *just* changed anyway).

Hope that helps!

Here's a link for futher reading on the subject: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The `$(this)[0]` pulls the name of the radio button so I can associate that with the selected answer. Seems to be the only way I can achieve that with the array I was given.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I forgot it's a radio button list so technically they would both change.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the display function out of the callback method for the $(document).ready() event.  IMHO, it belongs in the global space because it's being invoked by other functions in the global space.  It's just cleaner than relying on a Closure to keep a reference to an object hidden in an event handler.

EDIT:  I imagine the problem is the use of this, without stepping through the code.  Would things change if you use pass in the event object in your handler .change(), and use that to get a reference to the element?

Comment: With an "on()" function, that would work, but with "change()" it doesn't, unless the script is below the elements in question on the page.  The DOM has to render the element before you can assign direct listeners like that.  It's the same problem that pure javascript has, where listening for document load complete ensures all the elements are in the DOM.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my previous comment. Thanks for the feedback, I'll look into this.