# jQuery click() not working when switching radio set

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a code that has a set of radio buttons. I change the buttons set based on given conditions. I need to know what radio button the user has selected once I switch the set.  It works on the original set, but on the switched set click doesn't fire.

Here's a sample code. The original set of radio buttons work fine when checked and I get an alert of what the user selected.  Added a button to switch the radios to another set, but when I check a button in the new (switched) set click doesn't fire.

I greatly appreciate your help and suggestions.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
                var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='opt']:checked");
                alert(selected.val());
            });

            $("#switchRadioSetButton" ).click(function() {
                var secondSetRadios = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"opt\" value=\"B1\"/>B1<br/><input type=\"radio\" name=\"opt\" value=\"B2\"/>B2<br/>";
                $("#div1").html(secondSetRadios);
            });     

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" >
        <input type="radio" name="opt" value="A1"/>A1<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="opt" value="A2"/>A2<br/>
    </div>
    <button id="switchRadioSetButton">Switch Radio Set</button><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

so I think that the problem is like this one. Correct me if I'm wrong again. So basically the event is destroyed when you change the html of radio.

---

***Answer From other question***

This is most likely because the event is not delegated. When the page is loaded you bind the click events. But as the dom is manipulated (elements removed) the events are deleted. You would have to use a delegate for this.

[Why does this jQuery .change event stop working after .click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403034/why-does-this-jquery-change-event-stop-working-after-click-event)

---

***Code Removed***

```
$("input[name='opt']").click(function(){
    var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='opt']:checked");
    alert(selected.val());
});
```

***Code I Added***

```
$('#div1').on('change', ':radio', function(){
    var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='opt']:checked");
    alert(selected.val());
});
```

***Example***

https://jsfiddle.net/c37at0jn/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Changing the radio sets is not an issue.  My problem is once the sets are changed, click doesn't fire. In the actual program there is an elaborate navigational structure which I change based on unrelated conditions. The first time I paint the screen (actually using $("#div1").html(htmlContent1) -- not hardcoded) it works, but when I change the content and radio sets, click stops firing. Funny thing is if I use "append"  (e.g., $("#div1").append(htmlContent1);) Click keeps on firing for the first HTML radio sets, but in the subsequent appended htmls does not.

Comment: @tonyshams I updated my answer to fix the problem of the radio button not getting fired after clicking.

Comment: YES!! You solved it.  It works now. Thank you so very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use `prop()`

```
 $("input[type='radio']").prop(function(){
   //code goes here
 });
```

instead of `click()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried prop but it didn't work.